# Is it an Rvalue or Lvalue After a Cast

Tags: c++, compiler-bug, lvalue-to-rvalue

The code here test for lvalue or rvalue after a type cast:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <typename T>
T const f1(T  const &t) {
  printf("T const \n");
  return t;
}
template <typename T>
T  f1(T  &t) {
  printf("T\n");
  return t;
}
struct KK {
  int a;
};

int main()
{
  KK kk;
  kk.a=0;

  int ii;
  f1(kk);
  f1((KK)kk);

  f1(ii);
  f1((int)ii);
 return 0;
}
```

In gcc [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ccf850f3bcaa11d) the result is like this indicating rvalue resulted after a type cast:

```
T
T const 
T
T const
```

But in VC++2010, this is the result indicating rvalue only if it is a class type:

```
T
T const
T
T
```

So is it a compiler bug or just some undefined behaviour when type cast to int?

Comment: Please use an up-to-date compiler when you run these tests

Comment: @MarcoA. VC++2015 gives the same result with VC++2010

Comment: @MarcoA, sorry, I don't have. It's not free

Comment: but which one should be the correct result?

Comment: I bet my money on gcc, I think gcc is right

Comment: @Danh, but you don't have to pay for gcc, didn't you?

Comment: I think this is an extension in VS. There was something with binding to non const references, but it is too long ago for the details. If you add  `/Za` to disable them I guess you should get the same behavior like gcc. Yup works [online](http://rextester.com/GCQFH23306)

Comment: @mkaes: Why don't you write an answer then?

Comment: The description of the MS extension should be here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [expr.cast](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#1) (this is applicable from C++11 and later)

> The result of the expression (T) cast-expression is of type T. The result is an lvalue if T is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type and an xvalue if T is an rvalue reference to object type; **otherwise the result is a prvalue**. [ Note: If T is a non-class type that is cv-qualified, the cv-qualifiers are discarded when determining the type of the resulting prvalue; see Clause [expr].  — end note ]

---

For C++98:

> The result of the expression (T) cast-expression is of type T. The result is an lvalue if T is a reference type, otherwise the result is an rvalue. [ Note: if T is a non-class type that is cv-qualified, the cv-qualifiers are ignored when determining the type of the resulting rvalue; see 3.10. — end note ]

Then, gcc is right

---

From mkaes's comment, it seems like this is the *(arguably useful) MSVC extension*

Comment: The description of the MS extension should be here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8(v=vs.100).aspx